# Round variable in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to round my variable from this:

```
value.setText(Double.toString(value_variable));
```

where it shows 428.14539335171594

to this:

> 428.14

How can I modify this line to get rounded variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `DecimalFormat`:

```
double value_variable = 428.14539335171594d;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
String text = df.format(value_variable);
System.out.println(text);
```

**Output:**

```
428.14
```